# Why getppid() from the child return 1

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I was running the program

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
    pid_t pid, ppid;
    printf("Hello World1\n");
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        printf("I am the child\n");
        printf("The PID of child is %d\n",getpid());
        printf("The PID of parent of child is %d\n",getppid());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I am the parent\n");
        printf("The PID of parent is %d\n",getpid());
        printf("The PID of parent of parent is %d\n",getppid());        
    }
}
```

THe output I got was.

```
$ ./a.out 
Hello World1
I am the parent
The PID of parent is 3071
The PID of parent of parent is 2456
I am the child
The PID of child is 3072
The PID of parent of child is 1
```

I couldnt understand the line

> The PID of parent of child is 1

It should have been 3071?

Comment: You would observe the behavior you expect by adding appropriate `fflush(NULL);` (before the `fork`) and `sleep(1);` calls (in both then and else part of the `if`, and just before the end of `main`).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because parent process is finished by the time the child asks for its parent's pid.

When a process finishes, all its children are reassigned as children of the init process, which pid is 1.

Try using [`wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) in parent's code to wait for the child to execute. It should then work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

pid 1 is for init process and it looks like the parent process finished before the child could print.

If you edit the else part like this :-

```
else
    {
        printf("I am the parent\n");
        printf("The PID of parent is %d\n",getpid());
        printf("The PID of parent of parent is %d\n",getppid());   
        while(1);
    }
```

You should see the right output.